# app crash with Error exc_bad_instruction

Tags: swift

When I run my App ,This error does not apply to :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and

```
exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)
```

In this line

```
0x10a1a4b5e <+686>:   movq   0x144423(%rip), %rsi      ; "navigationBar"
```

I realized that the problem goes back to the line

```
 let navBar = self.navigationController!.navigationBar
            navBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 235/255.0, green: 251/255.0, blue: 223/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
            navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

But because it's what I tried to catch. Who knows what the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have `navigationController`. It's nil.

Comment: `navigationController ` is  in `AppDelegate.swift `
       
 this is code `let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have somewhere in your code `nagivationController:NavigationController!` or something, but that doesn't actually instantiate a navigationcontroller. So make sure you do `navigationController = UINavigationController()` somewhere.